Store big text in single CLOB column or break it into CHAR/VARCHAR2 rows?
Which one would be the better practice in terms of performance? Put big text data in a single CLOB column, or create a table, break the text from user input into multiple rows of 2000 lengths of varchar2, then querying it by concatenating it through PL/SQL function?
I will take input from Oracle APEX environment.

What should drive your decision is not primarily performance but rather a sound data model. What are you storing in that field? A large unstructured glob of non-programmatic text with no clear elements or divisions (like an email body, or customer service notes, etc..)? If so, CLOB is appropriate. You will likely write once and never (or very rarely) update, and probably very rarely read. While working with LOB datatypes is quite slow in comparison with normal datatypes, the choice of these datatypes assumes you won't need to access or change the contents very often, so it's a moot point.
If however the text you have in mind is programmatically meaningful and contains pieces of data that you'll need, then you should break it out into a properly modelled set of tables and attributes and not use any large text field. Avoid storing pieces of programmatically usable data inside a single field, no matter what the datatype.
Trying to imitate CLOBs by using a set of varchar2(2000/4000) rows is not a good idea, unless your text is naturally lined (like lines from a log file, in which case one variable-width row per line is actually a good idea). But arbitrarily splitting content up by size (datatype limit) will create a nightmare for coding.

I am currently making a code manager page on my personal software where I am storing useful codes and solutions I find during my job as this will make it easier to find. So I have developed a typical parent child form where in parent table I am storing key information on the code and storing the actual code on child table. As of now I am saving those codes by breaking it into varchar2(2000) column in the child table.

@Adnan, if what you're storing is code, which is strongly line-oriented, storing one line per varchar2(2000/4000) row with a line number of part of the key makes good sense. That's basically what Oracle itself did with dba_source. This allows you to create function-based indexes if necessary, whereas you cannot do that with a CLOB.  As long as you're not arbitrarily breaking up content, but doing so on natural separators, using varchar2 is sensible.

For Better Performance :
Using clob : use this when your use case is to a) retrieve entire text in one step b) edit large sections of text c) less frequent edits or updates to text.
Note : storing information to clob is easy and simple as it is a single step process .
Using splitting approach and placing in varchar : use this when your use case is to do a) frequent smaller edits to text or to smaller sections of the text.
Note : Saving by splitting and placing in varchar and combining while retrieving might cause complexities.
To measure the actual performance for each approach u can declare starting_time variable to capture start time in your script before performing task . You can get time using DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
starting_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

and create another variable to capture ending_time after performing operation .
ending_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;

Then  substracting start time with end time gives actual performance .
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total Time taken : ' || (ending_time - starting_time));

